# In ASP.NET Core 6, why language folders needed in Published output for System.Private.ServiceModel.resources.dll and how to eliminate them?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, dotnet-publish

In ASP.NET Core 6 when publishing as a self contained win-x86 website a bunch of language folders are created in the publish folder.

[image]

These folders contain a single dll which is `System.Private.ServiceModel.resources.dll`. These folders where not present with Asp.NET 5 as best I can tell and they add clutter/noise to the deployment that I'd prefer not to have.

Can you explain why all these localized versions of the `System.Private.ServiceModel.resources.dll` are needed for such a deployment?  Also since my website is only in English, can I safely delete all the language folders (ie. cs, de, es, fr, it, ja, ko, pl, pt-BR, ru, tr, zh-Hans, zh-Hant)?
Lastly, is there a better way to make these go away?  Some configuration someplace for example?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add `SatelliteResourceLanguages` to limit the folders.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the documentation for this change? In .NET 5 the `dotnet publish` command was not creating these folders.

Comment: This works, but does not eliminate the problem. It's not possible to set `SatelliteResourceLanguages` to empty to get rid of the language folders.